# Android video editing app design

Tags: adobe-illustrator, android, applications

I am developing a video editing helper app. I went with a dark design (for some reason everything even remotely like this has a dark UI), as flat and simple as possible.

I've worked on this for a very long time (it has at least 15-20 versions) and I'm finally ready for the final draft. Except, I'm not.

There's something off about this design. The jog wheel seems a little too plain. Also, the icons, there's something I'm missing...

Should I try to give the icons a little depth, or fill them with a subtle gradient?

Everything shown in the picture is rendered on the spot (except the grainy background). The icons are svg's, the buttons and the jog wheel are done by painting on panels. So there are some limitations to what I can achieve.

I should also point out the fact that the colors used for the buttons, text and icons are subject to user customization.

Anyway, if any single one of you can give me any kind of advice, however small, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you for your time.

[image: Activity]

Answer (score 1):

Don't take my advice as gospel, but, here are my two cents. In general, I think that you need a little more consistency in the design. Just make a few minor geometric changes, and you should be good to go.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: I'd love to see it with the changes made, if you decide to make the changes.

Comment: Well...
1) To be fixed.
2) Is fixed. I forgot to update the .ai file. (it's pretty much irrelevant, everything being rendered in android, however you are totally right)
3) They look awful centered. Awful, trust me, I've tried. Furthermore, the icons actually being there or not is subject to user choice. The user can remove the text, the icon, or have them both. The icons and / or text aligns automatically based on choice or content.
4)Deserves thought!

Answer (score -1):

I was just playing around with the placement of the icons. Thoughts?

[image]

Comment: i didn't downwote. But it's not going to work. On some tablets the buttons will be smaller. On others, larger. Plus, it really limits the available text space. By a lot. Thank you anyway!